# Type 'Database' has no member 'child'

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following Bug in my xCode Project: Type 'Database' has no member 'child'. It's my first time developing an app, so I tried to do the same as I saw in a YouTube Video, but there everything worked fine. Does anybody know a solution ? I tried nearly any Solution I found on the web, but nothing worked for me. 
Heres my complete code:

```
  func retrieveUsers() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    Database.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: value, with: { snapshot in

        let users = snapshot.value as! [String: AnyObject]
        self.user.removeAll()
        for (_, value) in users {
            if let uid = valu["uid"] as? String {
                if uid != Auth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid {
                    let userToShow = User()
                    if let fullName = value ["Full Name"] as? String, let imagePath = value["urlToImage"] as? String {
                        userToShow.fullName = fullName
                        userToShow.imagePath = imagePath
                        userToShow.userID = uid
                        self.user.append(userToShow)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    })
    ref.removeAllObservers()

}
```

Comment: You're probably looking for `ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey()...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>    let ref = Database.database().reference()
>
>    Database.child("users").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEvent(of: value, with: { snapshot in
> ```

In this code, `ref` is a variable and `Database` is a type. The first line instantiates an object of type `Database` and assigns it to `ref`. If you want to access that object in the second line, you need to use `ref`, not `Database`:

```
ref.child("users").queryOrderedByKey()...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - and sorry for asking, but I am new to coding :-)